# setting color to 3d blender model with min3d library

Tags: android, opengl-es, blender, min3d

I created a sample 3d blender model (sphere with blue color) using **blender tool** and exported to `.obj` . With min3D library i was used that `sphere_obj` and `sphere_mtl`. It is working fine **except color.** it is displaying in white color. I think I missed something but I can't found. I have no idea about it how to do so please provide me solution..

thanks in advance

[image: sample 3d sphere]

Sample3dDemoActivity.java

```
@Override
public void initScene() {
    scene.lights().add(new Light());
    scene.lights().add(new Light());
    Light myLight = new Light();
    myLight.position.setZ(150);
    scene.lights().add(myLight);
    IParser myParser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.OBJ, getResources(),
            "com.example.min3dexample:raw/sphere_obj", true);
    myParser.parse();
    faceObject3D = myParser.getParsedObject();
    faceObject3D.position().x = faceObject3D.position().y = faceObject3D
            .position().z = 0;
    // EDIT resize object here with below code
    // faceObject3D.scale().x = faceObject3D.scale().y =
    // faceObject3D.scale().z = 0.009f;
    faceObject3D.colorMaterialEnabled(true);

    scene.addChild(faceObject3D);
}
```

raw/sphere_mtl

```
# Blender MTL File: 'None'
# Material Count: 1

newmtl Material.001
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

raw/sphere_obj

```
# Blender v2.74 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib sphere_mtl
o Sphere
v -0.195090 0.980785 0.000000
v -0.382683 0.923880 0.000000
v -0.555570 0.831470 0.000000
v -0.707107 0.707107 0.000000
v -0.831470 0.555570 0.000000
v -0.923880 0.382683 0.000000
v -0.980785 0.195090 0.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v -0.980785 -0.195090 0.000000
v -0.923880 -0.382683 0.000000
v -0.831470 -0.555570 0.000000
v -0.707107 -0.707107 0.000000
v -0.555570 -0.831470 0.000000
v -0.382683 -0.923880 0.000000
v -0.195090 -0.980785 0.000000
v 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
v -0.191342 0.980785 -0.038060
v -0.375330 0.923880 -0.074658
v -0.544895 0.831470 -0.108386
v -0.693520 0.707107 -0.137950
v -0.815493 0.555570 -0.162212
v -0.906127 0.382683 -0.180240
v -0.961940 0.195090 -0.191342
v -0.980785 0.000000 -0.195090
v -0.961940 -0.195090 -0.191342
v -0.906127 -0.382683 -0.180240
v -0.815493 -0.555570 -0.162212
v -0.693520 -0.707107 -0.137950
v -0.544895 -0.831470 -0.108386
v -0.375330 -0.923880 -0.074658
v -0.191341 -0.980785 -0.038060
v -0.180240 0.980785 -0.074658
v -0.353553 0.923880 -0.146447
v -0.513280 0.831470 -0.212608
v -0.653281 0.707107 -0.270598
v -0.768178 0.555570 -0.318190
v -0.853553 0.382683 -0.353553
v -0.906127 0.195090 -0.375330
v -0.923879 0.000000 -0.382684
v -0.906127 -0.195090 -0.375330
v -0.853553 -0.382683 -0.353554
v -0.768178 -0.555570 -0.318190
v -0.653281 -0.707107 -0.270598
v -0.513280 -0.831470 -0.212608
v -0.353553 -0.923880 -0.146447
v -0.180240 -0.980785 -0.074658
v -0.162212 0.980785 -0.108387
v -0.318190 0.923880 -0.212608
v -0.461940 0.831470 -0.308658
v -0.587938 0.707107 -0.392848
v -0.691342 0.555570 -0.461940
v -0.768178 0.382683 -0.513280
v -0.815493 0.195090 -0.544895
v -0.831469 0.000000 -0.555570
v -0.815493 -0.195090 -0.544895
v -0.768178 -0.382683 -0.513280
v -0.691342 -0.555570 -0.461940
v -0.587938 -0.707107 -0.392848
v -0.461940 -0.831470 -0.308658
v -0.318189 -0.923880 -0.212608
v -0.162211 -0.980785 -0.108386
v -0.137950 0.980785 -0.137950
v -0.270598 0.923880 -0.270598
v -0.392847 0.831470 -0.392848
v -0.500000 0.707107 -0.500000
v -0.587938 0.555570 -0.587938
v -0.653281 0.382683 -0.653282
v -0.693520 0.195090 -0.693520
v -0.707107 0.000000 -0.707107
v -0.693520 -0.195090 -0.693520
v -0.653281 -0.382683 -0.653282
v -0.587938 -0.555570 -0.587938
v -0.500000 -0.707107 -0.500000
v -0.392847 -0.831470 -0.392848
v -0.270598 -0.923880 -0.270598
v -0.137949 -0.980785 -0.137950
v -0.108386 0.980785 -0.162212
v -0.212607 0.923880 -0.318190
v -0.308658 0.831470 -0.461940
v -0.392847 0.707107 -0.587938
v -0.461940 0.555570 -0.691342
v -0.513280 0.382683 -0.768178
v -0.544895 0.195090 -0.815493
v -0.555570 0.000000 -0.831470
v -0.544895 -0.195090 -0.815493
v -0.513280 -0.382683 -0.768178
v -0.461940 -0.555570 -0.691342
v -0.392847 -0.707107 -0.587938
v -0.308658 -0.831470 -0.461940
v -0.212607 -0.923880 -0.318190
v -0.108386 -0.980785 -0.162212
v -0.074658 0.980785 -0.180240
v -0.146446 0.923880 -0.353554
v -0.212607 0.831470 -0.513280
v -0.270598 0.707107 -0.653282
v -0.318189 0.555570 -0.768178
v -0.353553 0.382683 -0.853554
v -0.375330 0.195090 -0.906128
v -0.382683 0.000000 -0.923880
v -0.375330 -0.195090 -0.906128
v -0.353553 -0.382683 -0.853554
v -0.318189 -0.555570 -0.768178
v -0.270598 -0.707107 -0.653282
v -0.212607 -0.831470 -0.513280
v -0.146446 -0.923880 -0.353554
v -0.074658 -0.980785 -0.180240
v -0.038060 0.980785 -0.191342
v -0.074658 0.923880 -0.375331
v -0.108386 0.831470 -0.544895
v -0.137949 0.707107 -0.693520
v -0.162211 0.555570 -0.815493
v -0.180240 0.382683 -0.906128
v -0.191341 0.195090 -0.961940
v -0.195090 0.000000 -0.980785
v -0.191341 -0.195090 -0.961940
v -0.180240 -0.382683 -0.906128
v -0.162211 -0.555570 -0.815493
v -0.137949 -0.707107 -0.693520
v -0.108386 -0.831470 -0.544895
v -0.074658 -0.923880 -0.375330
v -0.038060 -0.980785 -0.191342
v 0.000000 0.980785 -0.195091
v 0.000000 0.923880 -0.382684
v 0.000000 0.831470 -0.555570
v 0.000000 0.707107 -0.707107
v 0.000000 0.555570 -0.831470
v 0.000000 0.382683 -0.923880
v 0.000000 0.195090 -0.980785
v 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
v 0.000000 -0.195090 -0.980785
v 0.000000 -0.382683 -0.923880
v 0.000000 -0.555570 -0.831470
v 0.000000 -0.707107 -0.707107
v 0.000000 -0.831470 -0.555570
v 0.000000 -0.923880 -0.382684
v 0.000000 -0.980785 -0.195090
v 0.038061 0.980785 -0.191342
v 0.074658 0.923880 -0.375331
v 0.108387 0.831470 -0.544895
v 0.137950 0.707107 -0.693520
v 0.162212 0.555570 -0.815493
v 0.180240 0.382683 -0.906128
v 0.191342 0.195090 -0.961940
v 0.195091 0.000000 -0.980785
v 0.191342 -0.195090 -0.961940
v 0.180240 -0.382683 -0.906128
v 0.162212 -0.555570 -0.815493
v 0.137950 -0.707107 -0.693520
v 0.108387 -0.831470 -0.544895
v 0.074658 -0.923880 -0.375330
v 0.038061 -0.980785 -0.191342
v 0.074658 0.980785 -0.180240
v 0.146447 0.923880 -0.353554
v 0.212608 0.831470 -0.513280
v 0.270598 0.707107 -0.653282
v 0.318190 0.555570 -0.768178
v 0.353554 0.382683 -0.853554
v 0.375331 0.195090 -0.906127
v 0.382684 0.000000 -0.923880
v 0.375331 -0.195090 -0.906127
v 0.353554 -0.382683 -0.853554
v 0.318190 -0.555570 -0.768178
v 0.270598 -0.707107 -0.653282
v 0.212608 -0.831470 -0.513280
v 0.146447 -0.923880 -0.353553
v 0.074658 -0.980785 -0.180240
v 0.108387 0.980785 -0.162212
v 0.212608 0.923880 -0.318190
v 0.308659 0.831470 -0.461940
v 0.392848 0.707107 -0.587938
v 0.461940 0.555570 -0.691342
v 0.513280 0.382683 -0.768178
v 0.544895 0.195090 -0.815493
v 0.555571 0.000000 -0.831470
v 0.544895 -0.195090 -0.815493
v 0.513280 -0.382683 -0.768178
v 0.461940 -0.555570 -0.691342
v 0.392848 -0.707107 -0.587938
v 0.308659 -0.831470 -0.461940
v 0.212608 -0.923880 -0.318190
v 0.108387 -0.980785 -0.162212
v 0.137950 0.980785 -0.137950
v 0.270599 0.923880 -0.270598
v 0.392848 0.831470 -0.392848
v 0.500000 0.707107 -0.500000
v 0.587938 0.555570 -0.587938
v 0.653282 0.382683 -0.653282
v 0.693520 0.195090 -0.693520
v 0.707107 0.000000 -0.707107
v 0.693520 -0.195090 -0.693520
v 0.653282 -0.382683 -0.653282
v 0.587938 -0.555570 -0.587938
v 0.500000 -0.707107 -0.500000
v 0.392848 -0.831470 -0.392848
v 0.270598 -0.923880 -0.270598
v 0.137950 -0.980785 -0.137950
v 0.162212 0.980785 -0.108386
v 0.318190 0.923880 -0.212608
v 0.461940 0.831470 -0.308658
v 0.587938 0.707107 -0.392848
v 0.691342 0.555570 -0.461940
v 0.768178 0.382683 -0.513280
v 0.815493 0.195090 -0.544895
v 0.831470 0.000000 -0.555570
v 0.815493 -0.195090 -0.544895
v 0.768178 -0.382683 -0.513280
v 0.691342 -0.555570 -0.461940
v 0.587938 -0.707107 -0.392848
v 0.461940 -0.831470 -0.308658
v 0.318190 -0.923880 -0.212608
v 0.162212 -0.980785 -0.108386
v 0.180240 0.980785 -0.074658
v 0.353554 0.923880 -0.146447
v 0.513280 0.831470 -0.212608
v 0.653282 0.707107 -0.270598
v 0.768178 0.555570 -0.318190
v 0.853554 0.382683 -0.353553
v 0.906128 0.195090 -0.375330
v 0.923880 0.000000 -0.382683
v 0.906128 -0.195090 -0.375330
v 0.853554 -0.382683 -0.353553
v 0.768178 -0.555570 -0.318190
v 0.653282 -0.707107 -0.270598
v 0.513280 -0.831470 -0.212608
v 0.353554 -0.923880 -0.146447
v 0.180240 -0.980785 -0.074658
v 0.191342 0.980785 -0.038060
v 0.375331 0.923880 -0.074658
v 0.544896 0.831470 -0.108386
v 0.693520 0.707107 -0.137950
v 0.815493 0.555570 -0.162212
v 0.906128 0.382683 -0.180240
v 0.961940 0.195090 -0.191342
v 0.980786 0.000000 -0.195090
v 0.961940 -0.195090 -0.191342
v 0.906128 -0.382683 -0.180240
v 0.815493 -0.555570 -0.162212
v 0.693520 -0.707107 -0.137950
v 0.544895 -0.831470 -0.108386
v 0.375331 -0.923880 -0.074658
v 0.191342 -0.980785 -0.038060
v 0.195091 0.980785 0.000000
v 0.382684 0.923880 -0.000000
v 0.555571 0.831470 -0.000000
v 0.707107 0.707107 0.000000
v 0.831470 0.555570 0.000000
v 0.923880 0.382683 -0.000000
v 0.980785 0.195090 0.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 0.980785 -0.195090 0.000000
v 0.923880 -0.382683 -0.000000
v 0.831470 -0.555570 0.000000
v 0.707107 -0.707107 0.000000
v 0.555570 -0.831470 0.000000
v 0.382684 -0.923880 -0.000000
v 0.195091 -0.980785 -0.000000
v 0.191342 0.980785 0.038060
v 0.375331 0.923880 0.074658
v 0.544896 0.831470 0.108386
v 0.693520 0.707107 0.137950
v 0.815493 0.555570 0.162212
v 0.906128 0.382683 0.180240
v 0.961940 0.195090 0.191342
v 0.980786 0.000000 0.195090
v 0.961940 -0.195090 0.191342
v 0.906128 -0.382683 0.180240
v 0.815493 -0.555570 0.162212
v 0.693520 -0.707107 0.137950
v 0.544895 -0.831470 0.108386
v 0.375331 -0.923880 0.074658
v 0.191342 -0.980785 0.038060
v 0.180240 0.980785 0.074658
v 0.353554 0.923880 0.146447
v 0.513280 0.831470 0.212608
v 0.653282 0.707107 0.270598
v 0.768178 0.555570 0.318190
v 0.853554 0.382683 0.353553
v 0.906127 0.195090 0.375330
v 0.923880 0.000000 0.382684
v 0.906127 -0.195090 0.375330
v 0.853554 -0.382683 0.353553
v 0.768178 -0.555570 0.318190
v 0.653282 -0.707107 0.270598
v 0.513280 -0.831470 0.212608
v 0.353554 -0.923880 0.146447
v 0.180240 -0.980785 0.074658
v 0.162212 0.980785 0.108386
v 0.318190 0.923880 0.212608
v 0.461940 0.831470 0.308658
v 0.587938 0.707107 0.392847
v 0.691342 0.555570 0.461940
v 0.768178 0.382683 0.513280
v 0.815493 0.195090 0.544895
v 0.831470 0.000000 0.555570
v 0.815493 -0.195090 0.544895
v 0.768178 -0.382683 0.513280
v 0.691342 -0.555570 0.461940
v 0.587938 -0.707107 0.392847
v 0.461940 -0.831470 0.308658
v 0.318190 -0.923880 0.212607
v 0.162212 -0.980785 0.108386
v 0.137950 0.980785 0.137950
v 0.270598 0.923880 0.270598
v 0.392848 0.831470 0.392848
v 0.500000 0.707107 0.500000
v 0.587938 0.555570 0.587938
v 0.653282 0.382683 0.653281
v 0.693520 0.195090 0.693520
v 0.707107 0.000000 0.707107
v 0.693520 -0.195090 0.693520
v 0.653282 -0.382683 0.653281
v 0.587938 -0.555570 0.587938
v 0.500000 -0.707107 0.500000
v 0.392848 -0.831470 0.392847
v 0.270598 -0.923880 0.270598
v 0.137950 -0.980785 0.137950
v 0.108387 0.980785 0.162212
v 0.212608 0.923880 0.318190
v 0.308659 0.831470 0.461940
v 0.392848 0.707107 0.587938
v 0.461940 0.555570 0.691342
v 0.513280 0.382683 0.768178
v 0.544895 0.195090 0.815493
v 0.555570 0.000000 0.831470
v 0.544895 -0.195090 0.815493
v 0.513280 -0.382683 0.768178
v 0.461940 -0.555570 0.691342
v 0.392848 -0.707107 0.587938
v 0.308658 -0.831470 0.461940
v 0.212608 -0.923880 0.318190
v 0.108387 -0.980785 0.162212
v 0.074658 0.980785 0.180240
v 0.146447 0.923880 0.353553
v 0.212608 0.831470 0.513280
v 0.270598 0.707107 0.653281
v 0.318190 0.555570 0.768177
v 0.353554 0.382683 0.853553
v 0.375330 0.195090 0.906127
v 0.382684 0.000000 0.923880
v 0.375330 -0.195090 0.906127
v 0.353554 -0.382683 0.853553
v 0.318190 -0.555570 0.768177
v 0.270598 -0.707107 0.653281
v 0.212608 -0.831470 0.513280
v 0.146447 -0.923880 0.353553
v 0.074658 -0.980785 0.180240
v 0.038061 0.980785 0.191342
v 0.074658 0.923880 0.375330
v 0.108387 0.831470 0.544895
v 0.137950 0.707107 0.693520
v 0.162212 0.555570 0.815493
v 0.180240 0.382683 0.906127
v 0.191342 0.195090 0.961939
v 0.195090 0.000000 0.980785
v 0.191342 -0.195090 0.961939
v 0.180240 -0.382683 0.906127
v 0.162212 -0.555570 0.815493
v 0.137950 -0.707107 0.693520
v 0.108387 -0.831470 0.544895
v 0.074658 -0.923880 0.375330
v 0.038061 -0.980785 0.191342
v 0.000000 0.980785 0.195090
v 0.000000 0.923880 0.382683
v 0.000000 0.831470 0.555570
v 0.000000 0.707107 0.707107
v 0.000000 0.555570 0.831469
v 0.000000 0.382683 0.923879
v 0.000000 0.195090 0.980785
v 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v 0.000000 -0.195090 0.980785
v 0.000000 -0.382683 0.923879
v 0.000000 -0.555570 0.831469
v 0.000000 -0.707107 0.707107
v 0.000000 -0.831470 0.555570
v 0.000000 -0.923880 0.382683
v 0.000000 -0.980785 0.195090
v -0.038060 0.980785 0.191342
v -0.074658 0.923880 0.375330
v -0.108386 0.831470 0.544895
v -0.137949 0.707107 0.693520
v -0.162211 0.555570 0.815493
v -0.180240 0.382683 0.906127
v -0.191342 0.195090 0.961939
v -0.195090 0.000000 0.980785
v -0.191342 -0.195090 0.961939
v -0.180240 -0.382683 0.906127
v -0.162211 -0.555570 0.815493
v -0.137949 -0.707107 0.693520
v -0.108386 -0.831470 0.544895
v -0.074658 -0.923880 0.375330
v -0.038060 -0.980785 0.191342
v 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
v -0.074658 0.980785 0.180240
v -0.146446 0.923880 0.353553
v -0.212607 0.831470 0.513280
v -0.270598 0.707107 0.653281
v -0.318189 0.555570 0.768177
v -0.353553 0.382683 0.853553
v -0.375330 0.195090 0.906127
v -0.382683 0.000000 0.923879
v -0.375330 -0.195090 0.906127
v -0.353553 -0.382683 0.853553
v -0.318189 -0.555570 0.768177
v -0.270598 -0.707107 0.653281
v -0.212607 -0.831470 0.513280
v -0.146446 -0.923880 0.353553
v -0.074657 -0.980785 0.180240
v -0.108386 0.980785 0.162212
v -0.212607 0.923880 0.318190
v -0.308658 0.831470 0.461940
v -0.392847 0.707107 0.587938
v -0.461939 0.555570 0.691341
v -0.513280 0.382683 0.768178
v -0.544895 0.195090 0.815493
v -0.555570 0.000000 0.831469
v -0.544895 -0.195090 0.815493
v -0.513280 -0.382683 0.768178
v -0.461939 -0.555570 0.691341
v -0.392847 -0.707107 0.587938
v -0.308658 -0.831470 0.461940
v -0.212607 -0.923880 0.318189
v -0.108386 -0.980785 0.162212
v -0.137949 0.980785 0.137950
v -0.270598 0.923880 0.270598
v -0.392847 0.831470 0.392847
v -0.500000 0.707107 0.500000
v -0.587937 0.555570 0.587937
v -0.653281 0.382683 0.653281
v -0.693519 0.195090 0.693519
v -0.707106 0.000000 0.707106
v -0.693519 -0.195090 0.693519
v -0.653281 -0.382683 0.653281
v -0.587937 -0.555570 0.587937
v -0.500000 -0.707107 0.500000
v -0.392847 -0.831470 0.392847
v -0.270598 -0.923880 0.270598
v -0.137949 -0.980785 0.137950
v -0.162211 0.980785 0.108386
v -0.318189 0.923880 0.212607
v -0.461939 0.831470 0.308658
v -0.587937 0.707107 0.392847
v -0.691341 0.555570 0.461939
v -0.768177 0.382683 0.513280
v -0.815492 0.195090 0.544895
v -0.831469 0.000000 0.555570
v -0.815492 -0.195090 0.544895
v -0.768177 -0.382683 0.513280
v -0.691341 -0.555570 0.461939
v -0.587937 -0.707107 0.392847
v -0.461939 -0.831470 0.308658
v -0.318189 -0.923880 0.212607
v -0.162211 -0.980785 0.108386
v -0.180240 0.980785 0.074658
v -0.353553 0.923880 0.146447
v -0.513280 0.831470 0.212607
v -0.653281 0.707107 0.270598
v -0.768177 0.555570 0.318189
v -0.853553 0.382683 0.353553
v -0.906127 0.195090 0.375330
v -0.923879 0.000000 0.382683
v -0.906127 -0.195090 0.375330
v -0.853553 -0.382683 0.353553
v -0.768177 -0.555570 0.318189
v -0.653281 -0.707107 0.270598
v -0.513279 -0.831470 0.212607
v -0.353553 -0.923880 0.146446
v -0.180240 -0.980785 0.074658
v -0.191342 0.980785 0.038060
v -0.375330 0.923880 0.074658
v -0.544895 0.831470 0.108386
v -0.693520 0.707107 0.137950
v -0.815492 0.555570 0.162211
v -0.906127 0.382683 0.180240
v -0.961939 0.195090 0.191341
v -0.980785 0.000000 0.195090
v -0.961939 -0.195090 0.191341
v -0.906127 -0.382683 0.180240
v -0.815492 -0.555570 0.162211
v -0.693520 -0.707107 0.137950
v -0.544895 -0.831470 0.108386
v -0.375330 -0.923880 0.074658
v -0.191341 -0.980785 0.038060
vn -0.770800 -0.632600 -0.075900
vn -0.952700 -0.289000 -0.093800
vn -0.990400 0.097600 -0.097500
vn -0.878600 0.469600 -0.086500
vn -0.633200 0.771500 -0.062400
vn -0.290200 -0.956500 -0.028600
vn -0.290200 0.956500 -0.028600
vn -0.633200 -0.771500 -0.062400
vn -0.878600 -0.469600 -0.086500
vn -0.990400 -0.097500 -0.097500
vn -0.952700 0.289000 -0.093800
vn -0.770800 0.632600 -0.075900
vn -0.470900 0.881000 -0.046400
vn -0.470900 -0.881000 -0.046400
vn -0.916100 0.289000 -0.277900
vn -0.741200 0.632600 -0.224800
vn -0.452800 0.881000 -0.137400
vn -0.452800 -0.881000 -0.137400
vn -0.741200 -0.632600 -0.224800
vn -0.916100 -0.289000 -0.277900
vn -0.952400 0.097600 -0.288900
vn -0.844800 0.469600 -0.256300
vn -0.608800 0.771500 -0.184700
vn -0.279000 -0.956500 -0.084600
vn -0.279000 0.956500 -0.084600
vn -0.608800 -0.771500 -0.184700
vn -0.844800 -0.469600 -0.256300
vn -0.952400 -0.097500 -0.288900
vn -0.844300 0.289000 -0.451300
vn -0.683100 0.632600 -0.365100
vn -0.417300 0.881000 -0.223100
vn -0.417300 -0.881000 -0.223000
vn -0.683100 -0.632600 -0.365100
vn -0.844300 -0.289000 -0.451300
vn -0.877700 0.097500 -0.469100
vn -0.778600 0.469600 -0.416200
vn -0.561100 0.771500 -0.299900
vn -0.257100 -0.956500 -0.137400
vn -0.257100 0.956500 -0.137400
vn -0.561100 -0.771500 -0.299900
vn -0.778600 -0.469600 -0.416200
vn -0.877700 -0.097500 -0.469100
vn -0.740000 0.289000 -0.607300
vn -0.598700 0.632600 -0.491300
vn -0.365800 0.881000 -0.300200
vn -0.365800 -0.881000 -0.300200
vn -0.598700 -0.632600 -0.491300
vn -0.740000 -0.289000 -0.607300
vn -0.769300 0.097600 -0.631400
vn -0.682500 0.469600 -0.560100
vn -0.491800 0.771500 -0.403600
vn -0.225400 -0.956500 -0.185000
vn -0.225400 0.956500 -0.185000
vn -0.491800 -0.771500 -0.403600
vn -0.682500 -0.469600 -0.560100
vn -0.769300 -0.097600 -0.631400
vn -0.607300 0.289000 -0.740000
vn -0.491300 0.632600 -0.598700
vn -0.300200 0.881000 -0.365800
vn -0.300200 -0.881000 -0.365800
vn -0.491300 -0.632600 -0.598700
vn -0.607300 -0.289000 -0.740000
vn -0.631400 0.097600 -0.769300
vn -0.560100 0.469600 -0.682500
vn -0.403600 0.771500 -0.491800
vn -0.185000 -0.956500 -0.225400
vn -0.185000 0.956500 -0.225400
vn -0.403600 -0.771500 -0.491800
vn -0.560100 -0.469600 -0.682500
vn -0.631400 -0.097600 -0.769300
vn -0.451300 0.289000 -0.844300
vn -0.365100 0.632600 -0.683100
vn -0.223100 0.881000 -0.417300
vn -0.223100 -0.881000 -0.417300
vn -0.365100 -0.632600 -0.683100
vn -0.451300 -0.289000 -0.844300
vn -0.469100 0.097600 -0.877700
vn -0.416200 0.469600 -0.778600
vn -0.299900 0.771500 -0.561100
vn -0.137400 -0.956500 -0.257100
vn -0.137400 0.956500 -0.257100
vn -0.299900 -0.771500 -0.561100
vn -0.416200 -0.469600 -0.778600
vn -0.469100 -0.097600 -0.877700
vn -0.277900 0.289000 -0.916100
vn -0.224800 0.632600 -0.741200
vn -0.137400 0.881000 -0.452800
vn -0.137400 -0.881000 -0.452800
vn -0.224800 -0.632600 -0.741200
vn -0.277900 -0.289000 -0.916100
vn -0.288900 0.097600 -0.952400
vn -0.256300 0.469600 -0.844800
vn -0.184700 0.771500 -0.608800
vn -0.084600 -0.956500 -0.279000
vn -0.084600 0.956500 -0.279000
vn -0.184700 -0.771500 -0.608800
vn -0.256300 -0.469600 -0.844800
vn -0.288900 -0.097600 -0.952400
vn -0.093800 0.289000 -0.952700
vn -0.075900 0.632600 -0.770800
vn -0.046400 0.881000 -0.470900
vn -0.046400 -0.881000 -0.470900
vn -0.075900 -0.632600 -0.770800
vn -0.093800 -0.289000 -0.952700
vn -0.097500 0.097600 -0.990400
vn -0.086500 0.469600 -0.878600
vn -0.062400 0.771500 -0.633200
vn -0.028600 -0.956500 -0.290200
vn -0.028600 0.956500 -0.290200
vn -0.062400 -0.771500 -0.633200
vn -0.086500 -0.469600 -0.878600
vn -0.097500 -0.097600 -0.990400
vn 0.093800 0.289000 -0.952700
vn 0.075900 0.632600 -0.770800
vn 0.046400 0.881000 -0.470900
vn 0.046400 -0.881000 -0.470900
vn 0.075900 -0.632600 -0.770800
vn 0.093800 -0.289000 -0.952700
vn 0.097600 0.097600 -0.990400
vn 0.086500 0.469600 -0.878600
vn 0.062400 0.771500 -0.633200
vn 0.028600 -0.956500 -0.290200
vn 0.028600 0.956500 -0.290200
vn 0.062400 -0.771500 -0.633200
vn 0.086500 -0.469600 -0.878600
vn 0.097500 -0.097600 -0.990400
vn 0.277900 0.289000 -0.916100
vn 0.224800 0.632600 -0.741200
vn 0.137400 0.881000 -0.452800
vn 0.137400 -0.881000 -0.452800
vn 0.224800 -0.632600 -0.741200
vn 0.277900 -0.289000 -0.916100
vn 0.288900 0.097600 -0.952400
vn 0.256300 0.469600 -0.844800
vn 0.184700 0.771500 -0.608800
vn 0.084600 -0.956500 -0.279000
vn 0.084600 0.956500 -0.279000
vn 0.184700 -0.771500 -0.608800
vn 0.256300 -0.469600 -0.844800
vn 0.288900 -0.097600 -0.952400
vn 0.451300 0.289000 -0.844300
vn 0.365100 0.632600 -0.683100
vn 0.223100 0.881000 -0.417300
vn 0.223100 -0.881000 -0.417300
vn 0.365100 -0.632600 -0.683100
vn 0.451300 -0.289000 -0.844300
vn 0.469100 0.097600 -0.877700
vn 0.416200 0.469600 -0.778600
vn 0.299900 0.771500 -0.561100
vn 0.137400 -0.956500 -0.257100
vn 0.137400 0.956500 -0.257100
vn 0.299900 -0.771500 -0.561100
vn 0.416200 -0.469600 -0.778600
vn 0.469100 -0.097600 -0.877700
vn 0.607300 0.289000 -0.740000
vn 0.491300 0.632600 -0.598700
vn 0.300200 0.881000 -0.365800
vn 0.300200 -0.881000 -0.365800
vn 0.491300 -0.632600 -0.598700
vn 0.607300 -0.289000 -0.740000
vn 0.631400 0.097600 -0.769300
vn 0.560100 0.469600 -0.682500
vn 0.403600 0.771500 -0.491800
vn 0.185000 -0.956500 -0.225400
vn 0.185000 0.956500 -0.225400
vn 0.403600 -0.771500 -0.491800
vn 0.560100 -0.469600 -0.682500
vn 0.631400 -0.097600 -0.769300
vn 0.740000 0.289000 -0.607300
vn 0.598700 0.632600 -0.491300
vn 0.365800 0.881000 -0.300200
vn 0.365800 -0.881000 -0.300200
vn 0.598700 -0.632600 -0.491300
vn 0.740000 -0.289000 -0.607300
vn 0.769300 0.097600 -0.631400
vn 0.682500 0.469600 -0.560100
vn 0.491800 0.771500 -0.403600
vn 0.225400 -0.956500 -0.185000
vn 0.225400 0.956500 -0.185000
vn 0.491800 -0.771500 -0.403600
vn 0.682500 -0.469600 -0.560100
vn 0.769300 -0.097600 -0.631400
vn -0.185000 0.956500 0.225400
vn -0.403600 -0.771500 0.491800
vn -0.560100 -0.469600 0.682500
vn -0.631400 -0.097600 0.769300
vn -0.740000 0.289000 0.607300
vn -0.598700 0.632600 0.491300
vn -0.365800 0.881000 0.300200
vn -0.365800 -0.881000 0.300200
vn -0.598700 -0.632600 0.491300
vn -0.740000 -0.289000 0.607300
vn -0.769300 0.097600 0.631400
vn -0.682500 0.469600 0.560100
vn -0.491800 0.771500 0.403600
vn -0.225400 -0.956500 0.185000
vn -0.225400 0.956500 0.185000
vn -0.491800 -0.771500 0.403600
vn -0.682500 -0.469600 0.560100
vn -0.769300 -0.097600 0.631400
vn -0.844300 0.289000 0.451300
vn -0.683100 0.632600 0.365100
vn -0.417300 0.881000 0.223000
vn -0.417300 -0.881000 0.223100
vn -0.683100 -0.632600 0.365100
vn -0.844300 -0.289000 0.451300
vn -0.877700 0.097600 0.469100
vn -0.778600 0.469600 0.416200
vn -0.561100 0.771500 0.299900
vn -0.257100 -0.956500 0.137400
vn -0.257100 0.956500 0.137400
vn -0.561100 -0.771500 0.299900
vn -0.778600 -0.469600 0.416200
vn -0.877700 -0.097600 0.469100
vn -0.916100 0.289000 0.277900
vn -0.741200 0.632600 0.224800
vn -0.452800 0.881000 0.137400
vn -0.452800 -0.881000 0.137400
vn -0.741200 -0.632600 0.224800
vn -0.916100 -0.289000 0.277900
vn -0.952400 0.097600 0.288900
vn -0.844800 0.469600 0.256300
vn -0.608800 0.771500 0.184700
vn -0.279000 -0.956500 0.084600
vn -0.279000 0.956500 0.084600
vn -0.608800 -0.771500 0.184700
vn -0.844800 -0.469600 0.256300
vn -0.952400 -0.097600 0.288900
vn -0.098000 0.995100 -0.009700
vn -0.098000 -0.995100 -0.009700
vn -0.094200 -0.995100 -0.028600
vn -0.094200 0.995100 -0.028600
vn -0.086900 -0.995100 -0.046400
vn -0.086900 0.995100 -0.046400
vn -0.076100 -0.995100 -0.062500
vn -0.076100 0.995100 -0.062500
vn -0.062500 -0.995100 -0.076100
vn -0.062500 0.995100 -0.076100
vn -0.046400 -0.995100 -0.086900
vn -0.046400 0.995100 -0.086900
vn -0.028600 -0.995100 -0.094200
vn -0.028600 0.995100 -0.094200
vn -0.009700 -0.995100 -0.098000
vn -0.009700 0.995100 -0.098000
vn 0.009700 -0.995100 -0.098000
vn 0.009700 0.995100 -0.098000
vn 0.028600 -0.995100 -0.094200
vn 0.028600 0.995100 -0.094200
vn 0.046400 -0.995100 -0.086900
vn 0.046400 0.995100 -0.086900
vn 0.062500 -0.995100 -0.076100
vn 0.062500 0.995100 -0.076100
vn 0.076100 -0.995100 -0.062500
vn 0.076100 0.995100 -0.062500
vn 0.086900 -0.995100 -0.046400
vn 0.086900 0.995100 -0.046400
vn 0.094200 -0.995100 -0.028600
vn 0.094200 0.995100 -0.028600
vn 0.098000 -0.995100 -0.009700
vn 0.098000 0.995100 -0.009700
vn 0.098000 -0.995100 0.009700
vn 0.098000 0.995100 0.009700
vn 0.094200 -0.995100 0.028600
vn 0.094200 0.995100 0.028600
vn 0.086900 -0.995100 0.046400
vn 0.086900 0.995100 0.046400
vn 0.076100 -0.995100 0.062500
vn 0.076100 0.995100 0.062500
vn 0.062500 -0.995100 0.076100
vn -0.086900 -0.995100 0.046400
vn -0.086900 0.995100 0.046400
vn -0.094200 -0.995100 0.028600
vn -0.094200 0.995100 0.028600
vn -0.952700 0.289000 0.093800
vn -0.770800 0.632600 0.075900
vn -0.098000 -0.995100 0.009700
vn -0.470900 0.881000 0.046400
vn -0.470900 -0.881000 0.046400
vn -0.990400 0.097600 0.097600
vn -0.878600 0.469600 0.086500
vn -0.633200 0.771500 0.062400
vn -0.290200 -0.956500 0.028600
vn -0.290200 0.956500 0.028600
vn 0.097500 0.097600 -0.990400
vn 0.097600 -0.097600 -0.990400
vn 0.223000 0.881000 -0.417300
vn 0.223000 -0.881000 -0.417300
vn 0.137400 -0.956600 -0.257100
vn 0.137400 -0.956500 0.257100
vn 0.028600 -0.956600 0.290200
vn -0.097600 0.097600 0.990400
vn -0.097500 -0.097600 0.990400
vn -0.223000 0.881000 0.417300
vn -0.417300 0.881000 0.223100
vn -0.417300 -0.881000 0.223000
vn -0.990400 0.097500 0.097600
vn -0.990400 -0.097600 0.097600
usemtl Material.001
s off
f 12//1 11//1 27//1
f 9//2 25//2 26//2
f 7//3 23//3 24//3
f 5//4 21//4 22//4
f 3//5 19//5 20//5
```

REMOVED SOME CODE (Blender model faces and `vn -0.xxxxxx 0.xxxxxx 0.xxxxxx` above `usemtl`) FROM `raw/sphere_obj` ,BECAUSE OF CHARACTER LIMIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you added the jpeg file in the drawable directory and added the path of the jpeg file in the mtl file. You can follow mat-d's tutorial if you have any doubt regarding it. http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-load-a-3d-obj-model-with-min3d-for-android/

Comment: thank you for your response @sreejith. Is there any way to set color directly without jpg/png?

Comment: I dont think setting color without adding jpg/png file is possible since you are using obj file for 3d plotting. I think you are using only blue color for the sphere so it wont be really hard to create an image file with one single color or download it from the web itself.